# Linq query to get unique and sort

Tags: c#, linq

I need a linq query to get unique list of objects, group them by Dep and get the value with highest progress.
I have a list of objects as shown below:

```
List<SomeObjects> lstObjects:
    lstObjects[0] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 1
    lstObjects[1] - Dep: Sales     Comp:ABC  Progress: 2
    lstObjects[2] - Dep: Marketing Comp:DEF  Progress: 2
    lstObjects[3] - Dep: Marketing Comp:DEF  Progress: 3
    lstObjects[4] - Dep: Sales     Comp:ABC  Progress: 1
    lstObjects[5] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 2
    lstObjects[6] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 1
    lstObjects[7] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 1
```

As you can see Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC, repeats itself with varying Progress:, I have to get unique list of objects with highest Progress.

```
    Eg: lstObjects[0] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 1
        lstObjects[5] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 2

        Here I should get, lstObjects[5] - Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 2

    In, lstObjects[2] - Dep: Marketing Comp:DEF  Progress: 2
        lstObjects[3] - Dep: Marketing Comp:DEF  Progress: 3

        In this I should get lstObjects[3] - Dep: Marketing Comp:DEF  Progress: 3

    In, lstObjects[1] - Dep: Sales     Comp:ABC  Progress: 2
        lstObjects[4] - Dep: Sales     Comp:ABC  Progress: 1

        In this I should get lstObjects[3] - Dep: Sales Comp:ABC  Progress: 2

        Finally my list should be:
        1)Dep: Marketing Comp:ABC  Progress: 2
        2)Dep: Marketing Comp:DEF  Progress: 3
        3)Dep: Sales     Comp:ABC  Progress: 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of 'psuedo data' is confusing and hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` on `Dep` and `Comp`.

```
var result = lstObjects
     .GroupBy(x=> new {x.Dep, x.Comp})
     .Select(x=> new 
      {
          Department = x.Key.Dep, 
          Comp = x.Key.Comp ,
          Progress =  x.Max(x => m.Progress)   
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

A GroupBy 2 Properties should work:

```
List<SomeObjects> uniqueWithMax = (from rec in lstObjects
                                    group rec by new { rec.Dep, rec.Comp } into grp
                                    select new SomeObjects
                                    {
                                        Dep = grp.Key.Dep,
                                        Comp = grp.Key.Comp,
                                        Progress = grp.Max(x => x.Progress)
                                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You start by grouping by `Dept` and `Comp`. Then for each group take the elements with the highest `Progress`. The later can be achieved in a several ways, my favorite for LINQ to Objects (with the lack of standard `MaxBy`) is using the [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) method in a linear time:

```
var result =
    (from e in lstObjects
     group e by new { e.Dep, e.Comp } into g
     select g.Aggregate((a, b) => b.Progress > a.Progress ? b : a))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var DepCompHighestProgress =
                      from d in lstObjects
                      group d by new { d.Dep, d.Comp } into oGrouped
                      select new
                      {
                          Dep = oGrouped.Key.Dep,
                          Comp = oGrouped.Key.Comp,
                          Progress = oGrouped.Max(depcomp => depcomp.Progress)
                      };
```